# Can not install openjdk-8-jre-headless on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: java

I was installing openjdk-8-jre-headless on ubuntu 14.04 LTS using repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa . 
Things were working since this morning but now installation is breaking with error message

> openjdk-8-jre-headless : Depends: ca-certificates-java but it is not
>   going to be installed.

Is this package removed from this repository as it was working this morning?

Comment: What happens if you run `apt-get install ca-certificates-java`? Usually, that provides more information *why* the package cannot be installed. (The package is clearly available from the repositories, but a dependency problem prevents its installation.)

Answer (score 3):

The repository was updated for trusty today.

https://launchpad.net/~openjdk-r/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

The dependency on ca-certificates-java requires a needed change detailed in this bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ca-certificates-java/+bug/1706442